# iOS - Positioning UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, interface-builder

I have a UIView and in interface builder I have set it's location to 160, 57.

I at some point during the apps life cycle, the UIView may move, and so I have a button to put it back to where it was before. So I use the following code:

```
[self.myView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 57)];
```

However, when the UIView moves back, it's not in exactly the same place as it was when the app first loaded. It's a tiny tiny bit to one side.

Any idea why this is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the view's location using `view.bounds.origin` instead of `view.center`.

Comment: How do I set view.bounds.origin? XCode tells me it's not assignable.

Comment: You need to set view.bounds (with a CGRect that has the origin that you want).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using:

```
[self.myView setCenter:CGPointMake(159.5, 57)];
```

I didn't realise CGPointMake would accept floating point values so I thought I had to use 159 (too little) or 160 (too much). 159.5 was just right though.

It still doesn't explain why 160 works in Interface builder but I can just set this value when the view loads anyway.

Thanks for everyone's answers.